# Manipulate differents tables and display information from one

Tags: mysql

Write an SQL statement to show the warehouse information for warehouses which do not have all SKU items in inventory

I tried this query but results: NULL

```
SELECT SKU
FROM SKU_DATA
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM INVENTORY 
         JOIN WAREHOUSE  ON INVENTORY.WAREHOUSEID = WAREHOUSE.WAREHOUSEID
        WHERE SKU_DATA.SKU =INVENTORY.SKU);
```

Here the different tables available

Inventory (WarehouseID,SKU,SKU_Description,QuantityOnHand,QuantityOnOrder)

Order_Item(OrderNumber,SKU,Quantity,Price,ExtendedPrice)

Retail_order(OrderNumber,StoreNumber,StoreZip,OrderMonth,OrderYear,OrderTotal)

SKU_Data(SKU,SKU_Description,Department,Buyer)

Warehouse(WarehouseID,WarehouseCity,WarehouseState,Manager,SquareFeet)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9mOK.png)

Comment: `WAREHOUSE.WAREHOUSEID` is not shown in the `Warehouse` table :)

Comment: It's a mistake. Warehouse(WarehouseID,WarehouseCity,WarehouseState,Manager,SquareFeet)

Comment: That's not the right approach - you have to establish all sku items then get warehouses who do not have all possible sku items in inventory - an selecting sku makes no sense when you ask for warehouses..

Comment: On the other hand the question could be wrong your code seems to look for skus which are not in all warehouses.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way will be just to count the number of unique SKUs in the `SKU_Data`, then select all the `WarehouseID` from the `Inventory` that have less than that number of unique SKUs.

Critically, this assumes a warehouse doesn't have a SKU that is missing from the SKU table.

Also assuming `Inventory(WarehouseID,SKU)` & `SKU_Data(SKU)` are unique

```
select WarehouseID from Inventory group by SKU
having count(*) < (select count(*) from SKU_Data)
```

I've not tested this, but I think it's about right :)

If this doesn't work, you can always select the `count(*)` into a local variable, something like

```
select @skunum := count(*) from SKU_Data
select WarehouseID from Inventory group by SKU having count(*) > @skunum
```

If you want to also check the warehouse has the item in stock, just add `where QuantityOnHand > 0`, after `from Inventory`

Comment: Could have inventory but no quantityonhand or on order OP does not make clear..

Comment: Yep, I thought of that later, but its easy to add `where Inventory.QuantityOnHand > 0`

Comment: I tried taht SELECT Warehouse.WarehouseID,Warehousestate,          COUNT(Distinct inventory.SKU) as 'InvCount' ,count(sku_data.SKU) as 'DataCount'
FROM WAREHOUSE
 INNER JOIN INVENTORY
  ON Warehouse.WarehouseID= Inventory.WarehouseID
   INNER JOIN SKU_DATA
    ON Inventory.SKU=SKU_DATA.SKU
    and 'InvCount' > 'DataCount'
Group by warehouse.warehouseID, Warehousestate

Comment: `select WarehouseID from Inventory group by WarehouseID having count(*) > @skunum`